# MVC custom class with generic list in my model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public class ViewModelTables : IEnumerable , IEnumerator
    {
        public List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>();
    }
```

I have created my own class to strongly type my view. How do I use the genericList of table Order to achieve my task?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var my2Tab = new ViewModelTables();
            //my2Tab.customer = (from m in dc.Customers
            //                   where m.CustomerID == "ALFKI"
            //                   select m).First();                        
            var list = (from m in dc.Orders
                     where m.CustomerID == "ALFKI"
                     select m).ToList();
            foreach (var v in list)
            {
                my2Tab.orderList.Add(v);
            }                      
            return View(my2Tab);
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.ViewModelTables', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcApplication1.Models.ViewModelTables]'.

Comment: Show the rest of your code so we can answer you...

Comment: I have edited the code. You can check it now

Comment: Never mind!!! I found the solution to this!!! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your view is defined to accept the viewmodel like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication1.Models.ViewModelTables>" %>
```

Then I would remove the `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` from the `ViewModelTables` class unless you have a specific reason why they are on the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Right click to Index action select Add View

Click to : Create a Strongly-typed view

Select ViewModelTables model in Model Class Combobox.

Select List from Scaffold template combobox.

Click add.

you can try to remove IEnumerable , IEnumerator from class definition.